# How can I pass a nested enum as an associated value but hide the nested enum's initialization?

Tags: swift, enums, access-modifiers, associated-types

I am trying to use some nested `enums` to create a network router. How can I build this so that the only items which are exposed are `buildURL`, `get(sort..)` and `search(query..)`. In other words, I do not want `SortType` (4th option) to show up here. [image: This is what the compiler shows].

As an example, I am able to call this, which I don't want to do: `let router = Food2ForkRouter.SortType.init(rawValue: "r")`

I could technically declare `SortType` outside of this `enum`, but then the logic is less contained and it really only makes sense here. If I mark my `enum` as `private` then I get a compiler error because I cannot use it as an `associated value`.

This is my code, you can plug it directly into Playground:

```
enum Food2ForkRouter  {
case search(query: String)
case get(sort: SortType) // <--- I want to be able to pass a SortType enum here

enum SortType : String {
    case rating = "r"
    case trendingness = "t"
}

var parameters : [String : String] {
    switch self {
    case .search(let query):
        return ["q" : query]
    case .get(let sort):
        return ["sort" : sort.rawValue]
    }
}

func buildURL() -> URL? {
    /*......*/
    return nil
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An enum doesn’t have a constructor so you can’t change it to `fileprivate` .